# i need to make status message on excel after calling the api

Tags: vba, excel

I need to make status message on excel after calling the api . status message in xml format so how to parse the data accurately.

Below given codes are using to get API info

```
 Sub Test()
 Dim xmlHTTP As Object
 Set xmlHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

 myURL = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx:15555/gateway/StatusTracking/1.0/shipment/tracking?housebill=cvvvv"
 xmlHTTP.Open "GET", myURL, False
 xmlHTTP.SetRequestHeader "APIKey", "xxxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
 xmlHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
 xmlHTTP.Send
 Dim strReap As String
  strReap = hReq.ResponseText
  Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
 If Not xmlDoc.LoadXML(strReap) Then

  MsgBox "Load error"
 End If
 Dim xnodelist As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList

 Set xnodelist = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ShipmentTracking")  
 Dim xnode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode Set xnode = xnodelist.Item(0)   
Dim obAtt1 As MSXML2.IXMLDOMAttribute   
 Dim obAtt2 As MSXML2.IXMLDOMAttribute
 Dim xChild As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
 Dim intRow As Integer
 intRow = 2
 Dim strCol1 As String
  strCol1 = "A"
  Dim strCol2 As String
  strCol1 = "B"
 Dim Shipment As String
 For Each xChild In xnode.ChildNodes
 Set obAtt1 = xChild.Attributes.getNamedItem("Shipment")
 ws.Cells(intRow, 2) = obAtt1    
 intRow = intRow + 1   
 Next xChild
 Set hReq = Nothing
 Set xmlDoc = Nothing
 End Sub
```

normal xml status message format given below

---

`<Shipment tracking>`

```
<type/>
 <object/>
```

`<properties/>`

`<Shipment>`

```
<Origin/>
<type/>
<properties/>
<LocationCode/>
<CountryCode/>
</Shipment> 
</Shipment tracking>
```

I am newbie in vba programming and i  tried with this code but not working fine. I just want output,from  shipment(xmltagname) to end in excel sheet. Please help me on this

Comment: All but one of your past posts are very heavily  downvoted.  Read [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how the site works.

Comment: There's nothing in the XML other than the tags.

Comment: @SMeaden thanks for your feed back. i am just a beginner in VBA. can you please help me to understand what i have to mention instead of calling attribute ?

Comment: @nyfinpaul : I have started an answer.  To be fair, the MSXML library is structured in a way that may throw newbies.  There is a lot of polymorphism going on which is fairly advanced programming concept.

Comment: this has prompted a blog post which I hope you'll find useful http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/05/vba-msxml2-uncompromising-interface.html

Answer (score 0):

You have written code `Attributes.getNamedItem` when in fact you have no attributes.  Also to query for elements I'd prefer `selectNodes` and `selectSingleNode` instead of `getElementsByTagName`.

So try

```
xChild.selectSingleNode("Shipment")
```

and change the declaration for the receiving variable from `IXMLDOMAttribute` to `IXMLDOMElement`

Comment: @S meadan, thanks for your valuable feedback. i changed the program accordingly but i got one error from                                    "For Each xChild In xnode.ChildNodes "    message is like   ' variable object or variable with not define     '